# Can we use ternary operator inside a Python function to change no. of arguments?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I've a function as follows,

```py
def func(args):
    # Do logic

func('1', '2')
```

Now I want to send three argument in the same function call conditionally. I know we can use `if else` with two function calls with varying arg count but **can I achieve this with a ternary op inside the func call?**

such as this,

```py
func(('1', '2', '3') if cond() else ('1', '2'))
```

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE** I’ve already skimmed the StackOverflow and raised this question. So kindly read it thoroughly before suggest closing this.

Comment: Use args and kwargs: func(arg1, arg2, *args) - local varialbe args will contain tuple of all remaining parameters.

Comment: I know the args & kwargs usage in Python. I want to know whether we can use ternary inside a function as I shown in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct an argument list as a list or tuple, then expand it when passing it as an argument to `func` as follows:

```
args = ('1', '2', '3') if cond () else ('1', '2')
func(*args)
```

If you want to do the entire thing inline, you can do:

```
func(*(('1', '2', '3') if cond () else ('1', '2')))
```

The last version shows how you could use the ternary if-else operator inline to construct the argument list, which I believe is what was being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use **ternary operator** inside a function call.

```py
def func(*args):
    print(len(args))

func(1 if True else 1, 2) # prints 1
func(1 if False else 1, 2) # prints 2
```

Comment: No, they both pass 2 arguments, and they both print 2. Try it. The first argument list is equivalent to `(1 if True else 1), 2`, and the second argument list is equivalent to `(1 if False else 1), 2`. In other words, they are both equivalent to `1, 2`. Adding parentheses around the else expression won't help, since that would just pass a tuple as the sole argument.